# .Net Move project add reference in solution references old location

Tags: .net, project

Somewhere in the past, we had a project that was moved to another location in our filesystem. It kept the same name. When attempting to reference this particular project (not dll) in another solution, an error message pops up saying that it can't find the project (references the old location).

We are using TFS for version control. I have used agent ransack to do a full text search on the entirety of our trunk looking for the old path and cannot find it. Is there any way (short of creating a new project and moving all the code there) to update the project so that VS will look for it in it's new location?

Comment: Open the project file in text editor. See if exist some reference to old paths.

Comment: As mentioned, I did a full text search on the entirety looking for that path. It's not in the project file and it's not anywhere else.